# Slow NIC Speed on 2 Dell Servers

Tags: networking, centos, cisco, dell

I’m getting very slow NIC speed (both LAN & WAN) on two Dell R610 servers. I have multiple other R610's with same specs, connected to the same Cisco 3750 switch and they're fine. I've done a lot of troubleshooting and still cannot fix the problem. My Observium shows no spikes on my network or aggressive traffic on any other server that would cause some bottle-necking of any kind.

Tried replacement NIC cards 
Tried multiple ports on server NIC and Cisco switch
Tried Centos 6.8 and Centos 7 fresh installations
Upgraded NIC drivers via Dell Repo (specific for Linux)
Replaced Cat5 cables
Rebooted Servers
GigE enabled on server and Cisco switch, full duplex
Tried both Google resolvers and data center resolvers

```
[root@localhost ~]# wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test
--2016-07-05 13:32:59--  http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test
Resolving cachefly.cachefly.net (cachefly.cachefly.net)... 205.234.175.175
Connecting to cachefly.cachefly.net (cachefly.cachefly.net)|205.234.175.175|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: â€˜/dev/nullâ€™

0% [                                                                                                                                                                                                    ] 162,475     24.4KB/s  eta 73m 24s


[root@localhost ~]# ethtool -i em1
driver: bnx2
version: 2.2.6
firmware-version: 7.12.19 bc 7.10.0 NCSI 2.0.13
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no   



[root@localhost ~]# ethtool em1
Settings for em1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes



[root@localhost ~]# lspci -v | grep Ethernet -A 1
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
--
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
--
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
--
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
```

From Cisco Switch, no errors:

```
Cisco3750#show interface Gi1/0/13
GigabitEthernet1/0/13 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 001f.6c8a.938d (bia 001f.6c8a.938d)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
     23470 packets input, 5854358 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 12 broadcasts (5 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 5 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     240225 packets output, 19478755 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: It sounds like you've ruled out any hardware/software issues. It's time for some packet captures. Start a tcpdump when you try to download a file and upload it somewhere.

Comment: The broadcom are now part of qlogic, did you get the lastest qlogic driver ? As I see broadcom on your input I fear you use latest broadcom driver from that fork only, as qlogic still do update, broadcom driver/firmware are like 2/3 year old

Comment: @yagmoth555 it's from Dell's driver site and driver is May 2016